# Converting Excel to CSV with C# getting extra , on each row

Tags: c#

Am converting an Excel file to a CSV in a Azure WebJob to keep the file in blob storage during the process using C# but am getting an extra comma after each row in my csv file.

Example:

1,Test,Doe,
2,Test,John,

Here is my code for producing the csv:

```
public static class ExcelToCSVConvertor
{
    public static List<BlobInput> Convert(List<BlobOutput> inputs)
    {
        var dataForBlobInput = new List<BlobInput>();
        try
        {
            foreach (BlobOutput item in inputs)
            {
                using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(item.BlobContent, false))
                {
                    foreach (Sheet _Sheet in document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>())
                    {
                        WorksheetPart _WorksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)document.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(_Sheet.Id);
                        Worksheet _Worksheet = _WorksheetPart.Worksheet;

                        SharedStringTablePart _SharedStringTablePart = document.WorkbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().First();
                        SharedStringItem[] _SharedStringItem = _SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.Elements<SharedStringItem>().ToArray();

                        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                        foreach (var row in _Worksheet.Descendants<Row>())
                        {
                            foreach (Cell _Cell in row)
                            {
                                string Value = string.Empty;
                                if (_Cell.CellValue != null)
                                {
                                    if (_Cell.DataType != null && _Cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
                                        Value = _SharedStringItem[int.Parse(_Cell.CellValue.Text)].InnerText;
                                    else
                                        Value = _Cell.CellValue.Text;
                                }
                                
                                stringBuilder.Append(string.Format("{0},", Value.Trim()));

                            }
                            stringBuilder.Append("\n");
                        }

 
                        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringBuilder.ToString().Trim());
                        string fileNameWithoutExtn = item.BlobName.ToString().Substring(0, item.BlobName.ToString().IndexOf("."));
                        string newFilename = $"{fileNameWithoutExtn}_{_Sheet.Name}.csv";
                        dataForBlobInput.Add(new BlobInput { BlobName = newFilename, BlobContent = data });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            throw Ex;
        }
        return dataForBlobInput;
    }        
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a `for` loop instead of a `foreach` loop through the row’s cells? If you change… `foreach (Cell _Cell in row)` … to … `for (int i = 0 , i < row.Cells.Count; i++) {…}` Then... in each iteration… Write the cells value, then an `if` statement for the comma… `if (i < row.Cells.Count – 1) { //add a comma }` …

Answer (score 0):

This line is adding comma after EVERY single value
`stringBuilder.Append(string.Format("{0},", Value.Trim()));`
1,
Test,
Doe,
2,
Test,
John,

You need to exclude the comma on last value in row (last iteration).
On last iteration foreach (Cell _Cell in row) stringBuilder.Append should be
`stringBuilder.Append(string.Format("{0}", Value.Trim()));`